# matlab displays following answer, how to display contents of 1X4 cell

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Matlab displays the following answer:

`[512x512 double]    [512x512 double]    {1x4 cell}`

How can you display the contents of the 1X4 cell?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `celldisp()`. Check out [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/celldisp.html) for examples.
2. Double-click it in the `Workspace`, it will display its content in `Variable Editor` (may need extra double-clicks here to see its real data).

Answer (score 2):

for each single datum you can use :

```
mycell{2,3}
```

it will show the content of the cell in that position.
for a list of data you can have:

```
mycell{:,1}
```

it will provide all the rows from the first column in the mycell cell.